# Multiple level relationships data insert on Laravel5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I try my best to describe my question in English

For example:

3 tables, **artists**, **albums** and **songs**, they all have foreign keys.

artists hasMany albums

albums hasMany songs

Because of some reason I **have to** insert many data in same time:

The source data **structure** is like:

```
{
  artists: [
     {
         name: 'Davie Bowie',
         albums: [
            {
                name: 'Space Oddity',
                songs: [
                   {
                       name: 'Space Oddity'
                   },
                   // ...
                ]
            },
            // ...
         ]
     },
     // ...
  ]
}
```

I insert artists and albums data like this:

```
$artist = Artist::create([]);
$albums = $artist->album()->createMany([]);
```

When I insert songs data, I have no idea how to make it, because there are many songs belong to different albums.

When I inserting data how to make sure the belong relationship is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over albums and insert songs:

```
foreach ($albums as $album) {
    $album->songs()->createMany([....]);
}
```